# add "extern C" as a compiler option for a symbol?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, extern

I'm working with FIPS Capable OpenSSL. The source code is sequestered and cannot be changed.

To link to the static version of the OpenSSL library, all we need to do is:

```
export FIPS_SIG=`find /usr/local/ssl -iname incore`
export CC=`find /usr/local/ssl -iname fipsld`
export FIPSLS_CC=`find /usr/bin -iname gcc`
```

Then, simply perform:

```
$CC $CFLAGS <sources> -o myprogram <openssl libs>
```

The reasons for the gyration is OpenSSL will insert an additional source file - `fips_premain.c` - and compile it with the program sources. (Some additional steps occur, but the compilation of `fips_premain.c` is the relevant step).

However, when using `g++`, a couple of symbols are undefined because they were compiled with the C compiler when OpenSSL was installed, and g++ cannot find them when invoked as above:

```
/tmp/fips_premain-20db15.o: In function `FINGERPRINT_premain()':
/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/lib/fips_premain.c:103: undefined reference to `FIPS_text_start()'
/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/lib/fips_premain.c:116: undefined reference to `FIPS_incore_fingerprint(unsigned char*, unsigned int)'
```

If I add the `--no-demangle` linker option, here's what is output:

```
/tmp/fips_premain-be4611.o: In function `_Z19FINGERPRINT_premainv':
/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/lib/fips_premain.c:103: undefined reference to `_Z15FIPS_text_startv'
/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/lib/fips_premain.c:116: undefined reference to `_Z23FIPS_incore_fingerprintPhj'
```

Here are the lines of interest in `fips_premain.c` (around line 85):

```
extern const void         *FIPS_text_start(),  *FIPS_text_end();
extern const unsigned char FIPS_rodata_start[], FIPS_rodata_end[];
extern unsigned char       FIPS_signature[20];
extern unsigned int        FIPS_incore_fingerprint(unsigned char *,unsigned int);
```

Is there a way to mark a symbol as `extern "C"` from the command line?

Comment: Can you not simply prefix `fips_premain.c` with `-x c` on the `g++` command line?

Comment: Thanks mockinterface. I don't compile `fips_premain.c`. Its compiled behind the scenes when `fipsld` encounters a call to the linker (I thinks its the absence of `-c`). So I can't cherry pick it and add a flag for it.

Comment: Then even if you could supply `extern C` from the command line (and you can't) what was your plan, if it is happening behind the scene and you don't have access to its compilation command line? Unless you find a way to hook the process, or regenerate the file yourself there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Sigh.....

Comment: I also tried adding a symbol alias with `defsym`, but it broke things in horrible ways. Those back end scripts are not very robust.

Comment: Why do you want those things compiled with g++?  I mean, other than convenience.  Could you just leave them as is, and change your code to use external C functions?

Comment: *Why* can't you change the code? Why can't you copy the code, change it, and discard the copy afterwards? Would tricking the compiler into reading the code different from what is stored on disk (via library interposition aka. `LD_PRELOAD`) be of any use? Would creating wrapper scripts around your compiler and linker programs be of any use? Is the `-include` argument to `gcc` of any use? Could you link an additional library which provides the C++ names as functions which forward to their C counterparts?

Comment: For those who find stumble upon this page, mockinterface and Mats Petersson helped with a solution. The entire solution can be found on the OpenSSL wiki at [fipsld and C++](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Fipsld_and_C%2B%2B).

Comment: @mockinterface - I found I was able to modify one of the scripts that are distributed with the FIPS source files. For whatever reason, the script was not sequestered, so I was able to add the `-x c` (and `-x none`) to get through the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supplying the `-x c` switch with `g++` before the file on the compilation command line will force it to be compiled as a C file instead of the default C++.

#### From the [Fipsld and C++](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Fipsld_and_C%2B%2B) page:

> Open fipsld++ and find occurrences where fips_premain.c is compiled. It is compiled through the variable {PREMAIN_C} ... 
>   
>   Change the lines so that -x c preceeds "${PREMAIN_C}", and -x none follows it.

```
${CC}  ${CANISTER_O_CMD:+"${CANISTER_O_CMD}"} \
    -x c "${PREMAIN_C}" -x none \
    ${_WL_PREMAIN} "$@"
```

> Forcing C compilation on fips_premain.c applies to all configurations (libraries, shared objects, and executables), so you are safe to apply it to all sections of fipsld++.