# Return to native file treatment after "-x c"

Tags: c++, c, clang

This is a follow up to [add “extern C” as a compiler option for a symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248074/add-extern-c-as-a-compiler-option-for-a-symbol) and  mockinterface's suggestion.

Using clang, `-x c` allow me to treat a subsequent file as a C file. However, it treats all subsequent files a s C files, including object files. For example, the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/clang++ /usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/lib/fipscanister.o -x c /usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/lib/fips_premain.c
-Wall -Wextra main.o /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -o main.exe -Wl,--no-demangle -ldl

main.o:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id
<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0003>
^
main.o:1:9: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0003>
                                           ^
main.o:1:10: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000>

<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0003>
^
main.o:1:9: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0003>
                                           ^
main.o:1:10: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000>
...
```

From the earlier question, I need the `-x c fips_premain.c` because if `fips_premain.c` is compiled with a C++ compiler, then I get unresolved symbols. (And `fips_premain.c` is sequestered by the FIPS process so it cannot be changed).

I tried switch back to native with `-x native` (similar to `-march`), but that produced an error.

How do I switch back to "native" treatment of subsequent files for linking?

Comment: Does a subsequent `-x c++` work?

Comment: No, `-x c++` produces the same errors.

Comment: For those who find stumble upon this page, mockinterface and Mats Petersson helped with a solution. The entire solution can be found on the OpenSSL wiki at [fipsld and C++](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Fipsld_and_C%2B%2B).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to rearrange your compile command such that `main.o` is befor `-x c` (since `-x c` tells the compiler that "no matter what extension I use, the following files are C source files" - so Clang tries to compile `main.o` as a source file, and failing as you can tell...)

You can do this by using `clang -c fips_premain.c`, and using `fips_premain.o` in the line that links things.

In other words, `-x c` followed by

> ```
>   -x language
>        Treat subsequent input files as having type language.
> ```

I haven't tested it, but it may work to do -x none after your .c file too - gcc manual says that this should work if the Clang compatibility to gcc works as it should. Edit: Can confirm that `-x none` does what can be expected.

Comment: `-x none` - that was it. `-x none` was not listed in the man pages for [Clang](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clang), but it was listed for GCC. I should have checked. Thanks.